# How use ref example with another ref example?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swaggerhub

I am trying to understand how to nest ref inside a ref..

I have 2 objects, ResponseObject and LastUpdatedAt:

```
ResponseObject:
  type: object
  properties:
    code:
      type: integer
      format: int32s
      minimum: 100
      maximum: 600
    message:
      type: string
    data:
      type: object
  required:
    - code
    - message
```

and

```
LastUpdatedAt:
  type: object
  properties:
    last_updated_at:
      type: long
      readOnly: true
      example: 1574933675150
```

What I want to achieve is making my example look like this:
[image: desired_result]

I keep trying without success, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
LastUpdatedAtResponse:
  schema:
    $ref: "#/components/schemas/ResponseObject"
  example:
    - code: 200
      message: 'Success'
      data:
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/LocalDataLastUpdatedAt"
        example:
          - lastUpdated: 1574933675150
```

but this ends up looking like this:

[image: current_state]

My end goal is to have all my objects use the ResponseObject but I can't seem to make it work.
Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `example` keyword does not support `$ref`. You need to specify the whole example value inline:

```yaml
LastUpdatedAtResponse:
  ...
  example:
    - code: 200
      message: 'Success'
      data:
        last_updated_at: 1574933675150
```

Note that `$ref` is supported in multiple `examples`, but it can only be used to reference the entire [Example Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#exampleObject), it's impossible to `$ref` just a part of an example.